# What is the probability that a permutation of $n$ elements has at least two points such that $f(i) = i$?

Tags: probability

> Let $n$ be a natural number $\geq 2$. Let $\langle\Omega, Pr\rangle$ be our probability space, where $\Omega$ is the set of all permutations of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $Pr$ is uniform distribution. Calculate the probability that the permutation that was chosen randomly from $\Omega$ has at least two points $i, j$ such that $f(i) = i$ and $f(j) = j$.

So, I thought about making a random variable $F$ that would count the number of points in a permutation but this would give us the expected value of the total sum of points like this, I don't know how to settle it for $\geq$ two points.

Would be happy for a direction

Comment: This is rather a combinatorical problem. Count all permutations and subtract those without fixed point and those with one fixed point. To calculate the latter, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers)

Answer (score 2):

The number of permutations of ${1,2,...,n}$ with no fixed points is $n! \sum^{n}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$ and the number of permutation with exactly 1 fixed point is $\sum^{n}_{k=1}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{n!}{(k-1)!}$

Hence the number of permutations with at least two fixed points is:

$n!-(n! \sum^{n}_{k=0}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}) -(\sum^{n}_{k=1}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{n!}{(k-1)!})$

So the required probability is.... I think you can take it from here.